# How to create non-popup dojo TooltipDialog style element

Tags: dojo

I have been using dojo TooltipDialog for a while for my project. It looks nice. You can see how it looks here: http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/test_TooltipDialog.html

However, all the TooltipDialog is opened as popup. What I want now is something with similar style as TooltipDialog, but statically embedded inside the page, so that it can show the association relationship for one element with other.

Is there any way I can do with dojo TooltipDialog to achieve this, or is there any other framework that I can make use of?

Thank you for your reading,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may open the dialog on page load with dojo.ready(), using :

```
 dijit.popup.open({
    popup: theTooltipDialog,
    around: dojo.byId('whateverNodeConnectedToThisTooltip')
 });
```

You may also need to disable the keyboard closing event (pressing ESC), by something like :

```
dojo.connect(theTooltipDialog.containerNode, "onkeypress", function(e){
    e.stopEvent();
});
```

(not tested)

Comment: Thank you Philippe, I will have a test and let you know.